# Pass user messages depending on request response

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, express, https

**Introduction**

OK, what I have is a app built in Node and Angular. I pass A users email to my backed using a post in Angular, from the backed the order in the backed is:

1. Get the email
2. Get API key
3. Post email and API key to API

I do this by posting email to backed then using node and express get email use promise resolve (first function) to pass the email to my third function as well as the API key retrieved from the second function.

**What I need**

1. Angular post to back end Node
2. Run first function, If first function has retrieved the email then run function 2. if not correct then pass information to the first post (Angular) to display message.
3. Run second function, if true run function 3
4. Finally run post with data collected from function 1 and 2, if post correctly pass 200 code to first function or pass to angular post.

**Needed**

Verification on the front end (Angular) on each step (function 1, 2 and 3 in Node) they can be response code so that I may print a different message depending on response code

**Objective**

A user post email on front end, then depending on if the email was accepted on the API let the user know, This is where different messages or redirects come in to play depending if it was a wrong or right email.

**My Code**

**Angular side**

This is where the first post to the Node back end happens, would be nice if this could get different response request depending on the results on the back-end.

```
var firstFunction = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                app.post('/back-end/controller', function (req, res) {
                    console.log(req.body);
                    var login = req.body.LoginEmail;

                    res.send(login);
                    resolve({
                        data_login_email: login
                    });
                });
                console.error("First done");
            }, 2000);
        });
    };
```

**Node side (all in controler.js)**

**First function**

I would like this to trigger function 2 if success if not send a response code back to the Angular request.

```
 var firstFunction = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            app.post('/back-end/controller', function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.body);
                var login = req.body.LoginEmail;
                //Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()]) .then(thirdFunction);
                //res.send(login);
                resolve({
                    data_login_email: login
                });
            });
            console.error("First done");
        }, 2000);
    });
};
```

**Second function**

This function gets API key, if This function is successful trigger function three.

```
 var secondFunction = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                nodePardot.PardotAPI({
                    userKey: userkey,
                    email: emailAdmin,
                    password: password,
                    DEBUG: false
                }, function (err, client) {
                    if (err) {
                        // Authentication failed
                        console.error("Authentication Failed", err);
                    } else {
                        // Authentication successful
                        var api_key = client.apiKey;
                        console.log("Authentication successful !", api_key);
                        resolve({data_api: api_key});
                    }
                });
                console.error("Second done");
            }, 2000);
        });
    };
```

**Third Function**

If second function passes then this function should run using the email from the first and the API key from the second, If success then pass pass success back to first function to pass give 200 success to the angular side, or directly send a request response to Angular, If fail then again let the front end know.

```
 function thirdFunction(result) {
        return new Promise(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var headers = {
                        'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    };
// Configure the request
                    var api = result[1].data_api;
                    var login_email = result[0].data_login_email;
                    var options = {
                        url: 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/read',
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: headers,
                        form: {
                            'email': login_email,
                            'user_key': userkey,
                            'api_key': api
                        },
                        json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
                    };

// Start the request
                    rp(options)
                        .then(function (parsedBody) {
                            console.info(login_email, "Is a user, login pass!");
                            // router.redirect('/login'); // main page url
                            //  res.send.status(200);
                        })
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            console.error("fail no such user");
                            // res.status(400).send()

                        });
                    console.error("Third done");
                }, 3000);
            }
        );
    }


Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()]) .then(thirdFunction);
```

If anyone knows how to do this please can you help, this is the last part of my app i need to get working, Thanks.

**Summery**

In summery I would like different response codes Angular side depending on where and when the function got to on backed or if it passed all three functions.

**Eg:**

- request code for fails to post to backed
- Fails to get API key on function 2
- Fails to send email to API on third function
- Email not present on API
- Email present on API and all pass, Your In !!

  **UPDATE**

I found I can pass a message back to my Angular post using the following, but how can I make this message different depending on what function has run ?

```
var firstFunction = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                app.post('/back-end/controller', function (req, res) {
                    console.log(req.body);
                    // res.status(500).send({ error: "boo:(" });
                    res.send('hello world');
                    var login = req.body.LoginEmail;
                    res.send(login);
                    resolve({
                        data_login_email: login
                    });
                });
                console.error("First done");
            }, 2000);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by merging 2 function into one (the retrieve function and post) then i changed the promise chain

```
 var firstFunction = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                nodePardot.PardotAPI({
                    userKey: userkey,
                    email: emailAdmin,
                    password: password,
                    DEBUG: false
                }, function (err, client) {
                    if (err) {
                        // Authentication failed
                        console.error("Authentication Failed", err);
                    } else {
                        // Authentication successful
                        var api_key = client.apiKey;
                        console.log("Success your API key is", api_key);
                        resolve({data_api: api_key});
                    }
                });
            }, 2000);
        });
    };


var secondFunction = function (result) {
    return new Promise(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            app.post('/back-end/controller', function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.body);
                var login = req.body.LoginEmail;
                var api = result[0].data_api;
                var headers = {
                    'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                };
                var options = {
                    url: 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/read',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: headers,
                    form: {
                        'email': login,
                        'user_key': userkey,
                        'api_key': api
                    },
                    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
                };

                if (login.length !== 0) { // maybe use node email validation ?
                    console.log("Email Accepted, Next posting to API.......");

                    rp(options)
                        .then(function (parsedBody) {
                            console.info(login, "Is a user, login pass!");
                            res.status(200).send({ user: login });
                        })
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            console.error("fail no such user");
                            res.status(400).send('fail to login');
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log("Failed to get email from front end");
                    res.status(404).send('Incorrect length');
                }
            });
        });
    });
};

Promise.all([firstFunction()]).then(secondFunction);
```